# 2001 Subaru Outback tires question

Tags: tires, subaru

I have a 2001 Subaru Outback needing new tires. The originals are 225 60 16, but I was wondering if I could go with 225 75 16 and not have the tires rub. Would this matter if I went with the 225 75 16 shown in this advert?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the stock 225/60R16 with a 225/75R16 will almost certainly rub on the strut.  Typically with Subarus you can go up one size (225/65R16, for example) without risking rubbing, but the tires shown would be three sizes larger, or almost 3 inches larger in diameter.